# Update object values on queue basis

Tags: javascript, queue, fifo

I have a bit of a problem with the following: I have an inventory array of objects, where each object is the same product purchased at a different time and cost. After I make a sale, I want to get the average cost based on units sold, and then return an updated array of objects (or a new one) with the updated value of those properties (in this case decreasing quantity until it gets to 0 and moving on to the next object).

For example a have the following array of inventory objects:

```
"shirts": [ 
    {
        "purchase_id": "vsibh",
        "dateOfPurchase": "17/04/2020, 22:44",
        "provider": "Adidas",
        "product": "Shirt",
        "sku": "2390",
        "cost": 50,
        "quantity": 400,
        "total": 20000
    }, 
    {
        "purchase_id": "wLqV2",
        "dateOfPurchase": "18/04/2020, 12:22",
        "provider": "Adidas",
        "product": "Shirt",
        "sku": "2390",
        "cost": 40,
        "quantity": 250,
        "total": 10000
    }, 
    {
        "purchase_id": "tCyyT",
        "dateOfPurchase": "20/04/2020, 21:17",
        "provider": "Adidas",
        "product": "Shirt",
        "sku": "2390",
        "cost": 35,
        "quantity": 600,
        "total": 21000
    }
]
```

If I sell 900 units I want to get the average cost for each shirt sold, which in this case would be 43,06 ( (400*50 + 250*40 + 250*35) / 900), and return an updated array with the decreased quantities that looks like this:

```
"shirts": [ 
    {
        "purchase_id": "vsibh",
        "dateOfPurchase": "17/04/2020, 22:44",
        "provider": "Adidas",
        "product": "Shirt",
        "sku": "2390",
        "cost": 50,
        "quantity": 0,
        "total": 0
    }, 
    {
        "purchase_id": "wLqV2",
        "dateOfPurchase": "18/04/2020, 12:22",
        "provider": "Adidas",
        "product": "Shirt",
        "sku": "2390",
        "cost": 40,
        "quantity": 0,
        "total": 0
    }, 
    {
        "purchase_id": "tCyyT",
        "dateOfPurchase": "20/04/2020, 21:17",
        "provider": "Adidas",
        "product": "Shirt",
        "sku": "2390",
        "cost": 35,
        "quantity": 350,
        "total": 12250
    }
]
```

The objects of the array are already ordered by date. I thought this problem would be fairly simple to resolve but i've been stuck for days trying to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear why you marked this with the "queue" tag. Do you have an *array* of objects, or a *queue* of objects? A queue doesn't look like the appropriate data structure to use for this problem.

Comment: I marked it as "queue" because the elements are used in a First In-First Out basis (if you make a sale you decrease the inventory quantity from the oldest object). I'm sorry if I didn't clear that up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values are sorted you can use `for of` loop and process items.

Take a look at the proposed solution.

```js
const quantity = 900;

const state = {
  "shirts": [{
      "purchase_id": "vsibh",
      "dateOfPurchase": "17/04/2020, 22:44",
      "provider": "Adidas",
      "product": "Shirt",
      "sku": "2390",
      "cost": 50,
      "quantity": 400,
      "total": 20000
    },
    {
      "purchase_id": "wLqV2",
      "dateOfPurchase": "18/04/2020, 12:22",
      "provider": "Adidas",
      "product": "Shirt",
      "sku": "2390",
      "cost": 40,
      "quantity": 250,
      "total": 10000
    },
    {
      "purchase_id": "tCyyT",
      "dateOfPurchase": "20/04/2020, 21:17",
      "provider": "Adidas",
      "product": "Shirt",
      "sku": "2390",
      "cost": 35,
      "quantity": 600,
      "total": 21000
    }
  ]
}

const compute = (state, property, quantity) => {
  const values = [...state[property]];
  let remainingQuantity = quantity;
  let result = [];

  let averageCost = 0;

  for (let value of values) {
    if (value.quantity < remainingQuantity) {
      remainingQuantity = remainingQuantity - value.quantity;
      averageCost = averageCost + (value.cost * value.quantity) / quantity;
      value.quantity = 0;
      value.total = 0;
    } else {
      if (remainingQuantity !== 0) {
        value.quantity = value.quantity - remainingQuantity;
        averageCost = averageCost + (value.cost * remainingQuantity) / quantity;
        remainingQuantity = 0;
        value.total = value.quantity * value.cost;
      }
    }

    result = [...result, value];
  }

  console.log(averageCost)

  return {
    ...state,
    [property]: result
  }
}

console.log(compute(state, "shirts", quantity));
```